# How can I JSON_decode arrays that has been treated with mysqli_real_escape_string, htmlspecialchars,strip_tags?

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

Sorry for the long title.

I am kind of paranoid, so I sanitized $_POST that was treated with JSON.stringify(order) via javascript with

```
$order = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_upload, htmlspecialchars( strip_tags($_POST['order'])));
```

before inserting into mysql through mysqli prepared statement.

But when I try to json_decode by

```
foreach(json_decode($row['order'], true) as $id =>$value){
    $sumArray[]= array("item" => $id, "value" => $value);
}
```

I get "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ..."

I know json_decode works when inserted value is

```
{"Hot water":"1"}
```

but not when inserted value is

```
{&quot;Hot water&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}
```

In this case, how can I json_decode? 
Thanks.

edit: I was poor at explaining what I really wanted. As I have mentioned earlier, I already used mysqli prepared statement for inserting the data. I am less worried about sql injection but to advanced xss attacks.

What i really wanted was just how to json_decode

```
{&quot;Hot water&quot;:&quot;1&quot;}
```

I decided to go easier method: dropping htmlspecialchars.
What I did was

```
$order = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_upload, strip_tags($_POST['order']));
```

then,

```
foreach(json_decode(stripslashes($row['order']), true) as $id =>$value){
$sumArray[]= array("item" => $id, "value" => $value);
```

}

This worked nicely

Comment: Don't sanitize, parameterize. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: The answer is simple: DON'T do any pointless and harmful things, so you won't have to redo them.

Comment: Go drop mysqli_real_escape_string as well